# Java Looking for specific letters in a sting

Tags: java, string

I was wondering how to iterate over a string and to check how many hi's come out

For example, if the string is "hihi" the count should output 2.

This is what I have so far

```
public static int countHi(String str) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.substring(i, i + 1) == "h") {
            if (str.substring(i, i + 1) == "i") {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "hihi";
    int i = countHi(str);
    System.out.println("number of hi = " + i);
}
```

Comment: At the moment you both of your substr are looking at the same letter from i to i +1. Also you should make sure your loop goes to str.length() - 2 for you implementation to not throw errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare instances (like `String`) with `.equals` (not `==`). However, here you can use `==` with [`String.charAt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-). Also, I would start with the second character and compare the character at the current index with `i` and the previous index with `h`. Like,

```
public static int countHi(String str) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i - 1) == 'h' && str.charAt(i) == 'i') {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Alternatively, compare the character at the current index with `h` and the character at the next index with `i` (but now you need to stop iterating a character earlier). Like,

```
public static int countHi(String str) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'h' && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'i') {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easy way:

```
public static int countHi(String str) {
    return split(str, -1).length - 1;
}
```

Note that you must pass `-1` as the second parameter of `split()`; without it, trailing blanks would be pruned from the result.

Answer (score 0):

For compactness and readability, maybe:

```
int count = 0;
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(“hi”).matcher(string)
while (matcher.find()) {
    count++;
}
```

This approach will work for any Regular Expression pattern, although it won’t be the most efficient.

Comment: There's compact, and then  there's [*compact*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63293158/256196) :)

Comment: Yes but compact is only good in my book when it’s simple and clear. The rest is just intellectual horsing around.